# Is it okay for an object to tell its owner to delete it

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I have a scenario that is somewhat like this:

```
class Owner {
public:
  enum Type {TypeB, TypeC};
  void swap(Type type);
private:
  A* m_a;
};

class A {
};

class B : public A {
  void foo();
  Owner* m_owner;
};

class C : public A {
  void bar();
  Owner* m_owner;
};

void Owner::swap(Type type) {
  if (type == TypeC) {
     delete m_a;
     m_a = new C();
  } else if (type == TypeB) {
     delete m_a;
     m_a = new B();
  }
}

void B::foo() {
  m_owner->swap(TypeC);
  // will be deleted after this!!
}
```

There's an owner class that has a pointer to a base type A. That object of type B has a back pointer to its owner. There is a scenario where we'd want that object to tell its owner to swap it for another A type: C.

Is it safe from B::foo to tell its owner to delete it? I know if you do anything after the call to Owner::swap() it will crash. It is kind of like a "delete this" scenario.

Comment: Don't call `delete on m_a` before you call `new C()`. This is not exception safe. If the new operation fails this will causes the stack to unwind and potentially lead to a double delete in the destructor of Owner (which I assume you left out for simplicity). Do a new/swap/delete or preferably use a smart pointer.

Comment: In `Owner::swap(Type type)`, the line `delete m_b;` should be `delete m_a;` since there is no member `m_b` in `Owner`.

Comment: @Martin the actual code does use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've defined `A`'s destructor as `virtual` then that is perfectly okay.

By the way, your code needs small correction:

```
else if (type == TypeB) {
     delete m_a; //not m_b, as Owner doesn't have any member named `m_b`.
     m_a = new B();
  }
```

But I'm wondering which object gets deleted here, the one which calls `swap` function? If so, then I would say there is a design problem with your classes, and your program may crash thereafter.

Comment: There is a design problem, but this is the least painful option I have; which is why I wanted to know if it is crazy or not.

Comment: congrats on hitting 10k! last time I checked this you were under :)

Answer (score 1):

It will crash (not surely crash, but it will start a memory corruption scenario) if after calling swap you try to access a field in the class.

All I'm saying is:

```
void B::foo() {
  //this valid
  m_owner->swap(TypeC);
  //this invalid
}
```

Comment: Why? The fields are re-assigned valid new values. The problem is rather that this method isn’t thread-safe.

Comment: Because the address of "this" will not change during that function, below the call to owner->swap the this pointer is still the same.

Comment: It's not completely thread-unsafe; so long as only one thread accesses a given `Owner` at a time, it can be thread-safe if `operator new` and `operator delete` are thread-safe, or alternately you could add an external mutex to protect the object.  Compare and contrast to the copy-on-write behavior of some implementations of `std::string`, where you think you made a private copy of a string for a thread, only to find out it dies when the thread tries to change the string, unless you make a global mutex to cover all string operations.

Answer (score 1):

It ok to say the object owner to delete the object as long as you don't use it anymore. It also ok for an object to commit suicide (`delete this`), the Standard doesn't make any moral judgments in this case.